# tftp server in ubuntu 9.04 not working ( transer timeout on GET and PUT)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, tftp

I configured my tftp server by reading [this](http://www.davidsudjiman.info/2006/03/27/installing-and-setting-tftpd-in-ubuntu/) tutorial in ubuntu 9.04.

when I connect from other linux it says **Transfer timeout** on GET and PUT command.

I tried from same machine ( ubuntu 9.04 ) too but getting same error.

please tell me what can be the problem?

Thanks, Sunny.

Answer (score 1):

worked when I made the lines between the { } braces tab-indented.